# Call function after timeout on Toast element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Toast element that appears when I press a button.

```
const [toast, addToast] = useToast();
addToast({
        title: t("transcriptionPage.cancelledTitle"),
        message: (
          <p>
            {t("transcriptionPage.cancelledMessage")}
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                setIsProjectLoaded(false);
                // Clear bubbles
                dispatchProject({ type: SET_REGION, payload: [] });
                connectSocket();
              }}
            >
              {t("transcriptionPage.retryButton")}
            </Button>
          </p>
        ),
        timeout: 10000,
        close: closeAsr(socket),
      });
```

And this is the implementation of `useToast`:

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import { Toast, ToastContainer } from "react-bootstrap";
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader";

const ERROR_TIMEOUT = 10000;

// Toast handler wrapper
export default function useToast() {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "delete") {
      return state.filter((_, i) => i !== action.id);
    } else {
      let toUpdate = state.find((toast) => toast.title === action.title);
      if (toUpdate) {
        toUpdate = action;
        return [
          ...state.filter((toast) => toast.title !== action.title),
          toUpdate,
        ];
      }
      return [...state, action]; // add new toast
    }
  }, []);

  const component = (
    <ToastContainer
      className="position-fixed p-2"
      position="top-center"
      style={{ zIndex: 10 }}
    >
      {toasts.map((toast, index) => (
        <Toast
          key={index}
          onClose={() => {
            setToasts({ type: "delete", id: index });
          }}
          delay={toast.variant !== "danger" ? toast.timeout : ERROR_TIMEOUT}
          autohide
          bg={toast.variant}
        >
          {toast.title && <Toast.Header>{toast.title}</Toast.Header>}
          {toast.message && (
            <Toast.Body>
              {toast.message}
              {toast.variant === "progress" && (
                <ClipLoader
                  css={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}
                  size={20}
                  color={"#2CB7DE"}
                  loading={true}
                />
              )}
            </Toast.Body>
          )}
        </Toast>
      ))}
    </ToastContainer>
  );

  return [component, setToasts];
}
```

How can I call the `closeAsr(socket)` function only after the timeout? So only if no action is taken within that timeout I want to call the `closeAsr` function.